# Const char * allowing to change the character value, why?

Tags: c++, constants

I have this code

```
int main()
{
    char A = 'E';

    const char * i;

    i = &A;

    A = 'B';

}
```

which actually compiles with MSVC, why?
Isn't a const char * supposed to point to a constant character variable? Why can I change A to 'B' in the last line?

Am I missing something?

Comment: You're not using a `const char *` on the last line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a difference between a constant of type `char` being pointed to (a.k.a. the *pointee*) and a constant pointer of type `char*`. If you want to protect a pointer from (accidental) modification, you can declare it constant:

```
char* p = '...';
char* const cp = 'Hello, World!'; // a constant pointer
cp[1] = ','; // okay, the pointee is not constant
cp = p;      // error, the pointer is constant
```

A variable pointer to a constant can change:

```
char *p = '...';
const char* pc = 'Hello, World!'; // pointer to a constant
pc[1] = ','; // error, the pointee is constant
pc = p;      // okay
```

And finally, you can declare a constant pointer to a constant with

```
const char* const cpc = 'Hello, World!';
cpc[1] = 'a'; // error, pointee cannot change
cpc = p;      // error, pointer cannot change
```

This is from §5.4.1 of “The C++ Programming Language”, Stroustrup.

You can change `A` to `'B'` in the last line, because `A` is of type `char` and therefore can be changed. It isn’t declared a `const char`, which would prevent you from doing so.

Answer (score 7):

A `const char*` only prevents you from modifying the pointed-to variable *through that pointer*. It does not, and indeed, cannot, ever, prevent you from modifying it through other means. `const` pointers and references would be of little use if they could only point or refer to `const` values.

Answer (score 4):

`const char*` implies that you can't modify the pointee *through* this pointer. That doesn't mean someone else won't be able to do it.